# bash script - sed to return ip address

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm developing a bash script and I'm trying to get an IPv4 address from a network interface that is ON, on this operation I'm using **ip addr** and **sed**, but something is wrong because I can't get IP from **sed**.

So, the script at some point have this:

```bsh
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet "
```

This supposedly returns:

```bsh
inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
```

And with **sed**, I want this:

```bsh
192.168.1.3/24
```

I have tried some regular expressions, but it only gives error or blank lines! How can I achieve this?

Comment: `| awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: I'd pipe it into another `grep -o [0-9.]\+/[0-9]\+`  (Sorry, I'd test that, but I'm booted to windows right now.)

Comment: @Petesh that works pretty fine! but it's not with **sed**

Comment: @PauloOliveira requiring the use of `sed` is a little bit odd from my perspective… almost like it's a homework exercise

Comment: @Petesh you was the first to answer, but instead of an answer you put a comment, so I couldn't "accept" your suggestion :(

Comment: `ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | sed -nr 's/.*inet ([^ ]+).*/\1/p'
```

EDIT: Explanatory words as requested.

```
-n in sed suppressed automatic printing of input line
-r turns on extended regular expressions




s/.*inet ([^ ]+).*/\1/p
```

Search for a anything followed by inet and a space, remember everything [that's the parentheses] that's not a space AFTER that space, followed by anything, and replace everything with the remembered thing [\1] (the IP address), and then print that line (p).

Comment: to remove the mask in one shot : ```ip -4 addr show  eno1 | sed -nr 's|.*inet ([^ ]+)/.*|\1|p'```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for sed, so here's an answer that works using GNU sed version 4.2.1. It's really specific, and very overbaked for what you need. Based on your `ip addr show` command, I assume this is a Linux.

```
ip addr show dev eth0 \
  | sed -n '/^\s\+inet\s\+/s/^\s\+inet\s\+\(.*\)\s\+brd\s.*$/\1/p'`
```

An easier way using awk:

`ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}'`

Comment: This also like the `awk` solution. This work for me on OS X: `ifconfig vnic0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ]* //' -e 's/ .*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to directly find out your answer.

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep -P '\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+\/\d+' -o
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, both of the answers with sed and awk are quite good. In order to just get only the IP without the subnet mask, you could proceed further just like this:

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | sed -nr 's/.*inet ([^ ]+).*/\1/p' **| cut -f1 -d'/'**
```

or

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}' **| cut -f1 -d'/'**
```

or

Even better:

```
ip route get 255.255.255.255 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4}'
```

This should output only the IP Address.